# How to change payment method from one to another of the existing order in magento by programming way?

Tags: magento, payment

I need change the payment method of an existing order, programically, what you can suggest?

```
        $quote = $order->getQuote();
        $payment = $quote->getPayment();
        $payment->importData($data);
        $quote->save();
```

the correct solution is here, which is based upon the solution from Rajiv, the payment method in the order details of customer account in the frontend and the payment method in the order details in the order management of admin panel both changed after the following codes snippet, thanks to Rajiv!

```
    $orderId = '100000009'; // Incremented Order Id
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$payment = $order->getQuote()->getPayment();
$payment->setMethod('test'); // Assuming 'test' is updated payment method
$payment->save();
$order->save();
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$payment->setMethod('test'); // Assuming 'test' is updated payment method
$payment->save();
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try below code to update payment method of existing order:

```
$orderId = '100000009'; // Incremented Order Id
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$payment->setMethod('test'); // Assuming 'test' is updated payment method
$payment->save();
$order->save();
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Hi Rajiv, thanks, but i have add this code snippit to the program, and run the following code after the prevous code snippet, the payment method in the order does not changed:         echo $order->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();

Comment: For the old order Quote will not work. Do you want to change payment Method or Payment Method Title of already placed order?

Comment: it is same result after caull the snippet, $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle(); .

Comment: I just want to change the payment method of an unpaid active existed order which is set with another payment method. the goal is let ppl have a chance to change the order's payment method.

Comment: The code I have provided is doing same. It load exited order by Incremented Order Id, then it set New Payment Method and save payment and order. Here I as assuming Payment Method name is 'test'. have you tried this?

Comment: yes, i have two install payment methods in my system, call it as "atest" and "btest", both works. I need to change the payment method of an exisiting active nopaid order from "atest" to "btest", but not changed after your snippet. And for the code, $_order->getQuote()->getPayment()->getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()."oid/".$_order->getRealOrderId(); ?>/" , not changed too.

Comment: when i channged the payment method in an existing order, the updates will shown up in the order details of the admin panel too, i.e., I will see the order shown in the order mangagement of the admin panel with new payment method.

Comment: Hi Rajiv, your code works but need updates, please check my updated questions, you are great!!! :)

Comment: If it's helpful and working... you should mark my answer correct and helpful.

Comment: Yes, Rajiv, I have set your answer to useful and accepted, thanks again.